# Why UISwipeGestureRecognizer does not have response?

Tags: ios7, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I try to use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to detect vertical direction in my `UIView`.
My view's size is {0,0,1024,`1536`}, which means the height is two times of full screen's height, **also means half of the view is on screen and half of the view is off screen.** 
My purpose is to move the view's frame down to {0,`-768`,1024,1536} when `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown` is detected, and move the view up to {0,0,1024,1536} when `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp` is detected.

please refer to the diagram
[image]
**The problem**
Initially the view's frame is {0,0,1024,1536}, and I got the response when `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown` is detected and offscreen part moved up. 
After that I got no response when I swiped on the screen.

My I know how do I solve this problem? 
I have tried many methods, but not solve my problem. 
The problem probably is caused by the offscreen part.

**Update**
Firstly I tried to use UIScrollView to achieve, but failed.
Problem is the vertical detection of scroll view is not very accurate, and always mislead me 
move up/down views.

And I wish to move view directly not gradually.

Therefore I give up UIScrollView.

---

My Code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   // ...
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer * upSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleUpSwipe:)];
   [upSwipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:upSwipe];

   UISwipeGestureRecognizer * downSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleDownSwipe:)];
   [downSwipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:downSwipe];
   //...
}

- (void)toggleUpSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipeGesture
{
    //...
}

- (void)toggleDownSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipeGesture
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using UIscrollview instead of using gestures on viewcontroller.
On using UIscrollview , You can give the content size any size that you want , also scrolling up and down will be already implemented without having to use gesture recogniser.

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
swipeLeft.direction =UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
swipeRight.direction =UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

Also

```
 -(IBAction)swipeLeft:(id)sender
{
            //...
}
-(IBAction)swipeRight:(id)sender
{
       //...
}
```

Also include `<UISwipreGestureDelegate>` on .h

Comment: thanks. I tried before, the result is same. My selector calls can be called for onscreen part, however the offscreen part doesn't have response when swiping.